# JavaScript Equivelant of declare in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a line of code in my Next JS application that uses a variable from a script src in the app.tsx page like so

app.tsx:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

config.ts:

```
declare var Stripe:any
const stripe = Stripe("stripe publishable key")
```

This works because TS doesn't recognize the variable Stripe, but at build time it's loaded in from the script and it can be initializes. The declare statement bypasses the error without giving the variable a previous value. But when the TypeScript is compiled to JS with npm run build, the declare statement disapears and I get an error before the build completes. So, are there any other ways I could bypass the error similare to a declare statement, or maybe a way of better importing the script?

Comment: `declare` doesn't generate any javascript code. It just tells the ts compiler there is a `Stripe` identifier available in the current scope.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, but my question is that is there any JS equivelant that will do the same thing

Comment: install Stripe from npm and `import` instead of adding it via `script` tag

Comment: It's not that declare is doing magic, it's sole purpose is, as the developer, saying "don't worry about this random thing typescript, I know it's there even if you don't see it". If you're getting an error in JavaScript, it's because you're not creating Stripe correctly and it actually doesn't exist in scope.

Comment: I believe that the Stripe npm package only works for backend code, unlike what I'm trying to do which is the function stripe.redirectToCheckout(). I've tried, and I get an undefined error

Answer (score 0):

this work fine becasuse the type "any" includes function type,and typescript is working before build,you should know typescript is a tool for convenience during development.
the result of error is Stripe is a undefined varible,undefined variable can't be execute. so when execute the code,it will get error.so build tools can detect it,it nothing to do typescript.
the right way is:

```
declare var Stripe:(value: string) => {...}
const stripe = Stripe("stripe publishable key")
```

Comment: Alright, but is there any way to bypass this error in javascript or import stripe in a way that doesn't throw an error

Comment: because you use Stripe as a function, so only can you make Stripe to a Function,can pass this error. for Example:    ` declare var Stripe:(value: string) => {return value};
const stripe = Stripe("stripe publishable key")`